# How to avoid two barButtons in NavigationBar could be pressed in same time?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I found this problem in my app.

"BackBarButton" and "rightBarButton" could be touched in same time.And then both of the actions will be called.

I know there is "exclusiveTouch" in **UIView** to solve this kind of problem.But **UIBarButton** is not subClass of it.

Could anyone help me out??
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more information about why is it that you're trying to ensure that 2 bar button can't be pressed simultaneously?

Comment: 99.999% of the users are going to select one or the other. not both at the same time

Comment: @SanjitSaluja It's a test case.And in this case my app crashes.So I want to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a clean and general case answer, I've not got one.

A less elegant solution that should work just fine for your app, though.  Just create a `BOOL` flag in your class and set it when you are actively responding to one of your `UIBarButton` presses, then clear it when you are done responding to that button press.  In each of your responses, just check for the flag.

So, in your init for your class:  `isBusy = NO;`

Then in each selector:

```
if (!isBusy) {
   isBusy = YES;
   //Do yer stuff for this selector
   isBusy = NO;
}
```